# How to select a newly added ListBox entry?

Tags: logic, delphi

I have a listbox (ListBox1) and a button (Button1). When I click on the button, a new item is added to the listbox. If I click on the newly added item, it is highlighted. If I add another item to the listbox, the previously selected item is still highlighted. I want it so that the item that I add gets highlighted (selected) automatically.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the `ItemIndex` property of the list box. For example...

```
ListBox1.ItemIndex := ListBox1.Items.Count-1;
```

The `-1` is because lists are `0` based.

---

Alternatively, you can obtain the index of the new item directly when you call `Add()`, so...

```
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I:= ListBox1.Items.Add('Some Value');
  ListBox1.ItemIndex := I;
end;
```

Or even more simple:

```
ListBox1.ItemIndex := ListBox1.Items.Add('Some Value');
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for the input. The problem is, I only want to select the newly added item. Your solution means that whenever I click the button, the first item in the listbox will be selected, not the item that I have just added to the listbox, unless I'm not quite understanding your solution.

Comment: This selects the *last* item, not the *first*. You can set the `ItemIndex` to whatever you want, and in my example, it's the last item in the list.

Comment: My mistake, some other crap code I wrote was interfering with your code. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: The `Items.Add()` method returns the index of the newly added item.  Assign that index to the `ItemIndex` property, eg: `ListBox1.ItemIndex := ListBox1.Items.Add(...);`